# Inserting data into a MySQL database, specifying particular tables

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have a query

```
     SELECT ultrait_wpl_properties.id, location1_name, location3_name, location4_name, 
     field_312, field_42, post_code, lot_area, price, bedrooms, bathrooms, field_308, 
     googlemap_lt, googlemap_ln, street, street_no, ultrait_wpl_property_types.name, 
     ultrait_wpl_items.item_name 
     FROM ultrait_wpl_properties 
     JOIN ultrait_wpl_property_types 
     ON ultrait_wpl_properties.property_type = ultrait_wpl_property_types.id 
     JOIN ultrait_wpl_items ON ultrait_wpl_properties.id = ultrait_wpl_items.id 
     ORDER BY ultrait_wpl_properties.id
```

As you can see I'm using JOINS. When it comes to inserting a new record is there a way to create an INSERT statement that will incorporate these?

What I mean is if I have the data for all the fields specified in the above query can I write an INSERT that will insert the data into the correct tables? I am currently researching this matter also but if anyone could provide any insight it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Or the slightly longer answer: no, the SQL standard does not provide this option.

There is a workaround: you can create a `STORED PROCEDURE` that accepts the input from the query and splits it into multiple `INSERT` statements. However: this solution will not have any of the flexibility of standard SQL statements.

Also it is not a simple matter if you have three tables joined by keys you may as well have 2 updates and one insert instead of three inserts.

Comment: My issue arised because I am getting the data to insert back from an XML Feed, in the feed the useer did not want to see the ID relating to the property type, just the tpe. Given this I used a join to just retrieve the type. The problem I face now is because the type is related to an ID which then links to the type in another table I cannot just place the type back into my database....

Comment: If you are just trying to look up additional values (look for type id through type description) you have two basic options: 1) write an insert where the inserted value of the id is the result of a mini-query. 2) Use a program or an XSLT stylesheet to insert the id's into the existing rows. There are also many closed and open source solutions available that will perform these kinds transformations before import for you. Search "message servers".

Comment: So in theory could i use a SELECT inside an INSERT in order to say INSERT where this statement is true?

Comment: Most SQL versions allows this, but it must concern SQL queries returning a single value. E.g.: INSERT INTO x VALUES (12, (SELECT MAX(Y) FROM Z), CURRENT_TIME)